# Is there a JQuery plugin that can give you a tooltip underneath your mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Just a simple jquery tooltip when you rollover a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

This seems like its what you are looking for.

Comment: I mean that when I roll over a div, a tooltip appears, but follows my mouse(on the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

[Simpletip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/)

Comment: noting that simpletip has been superseded by http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

and confirming that it does what poster requests

Answer (score 0):

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html
Small and simple library and it also has any grreat plugins you can use.